# Python: count TP, FP, FN и TN

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have dataframe with true class and class, that were predicted by some algorithm.

```
     true  pred
0       1     0
1       1     1
2       1     1
3       0     0
4       1     1
```

I try to use

```
def classification(y_actual, y_hat):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0

    for i in range(len(y_hat)): 
        if y_actual[i] == y_hat[i] == 1:
           TP += 1
    for i in range(len(y_hat)): 
        if y_actual[i] == 1 and y_actual != y_hat[i]:
           FP += 1
    for i in range(len(y_hat)): 
        if y_actual[i] == y_hat[i] == 0:
           TN += 1
    for i in range(len(y_hat)): 
        if y_actual[i] == 0 and y_actual != y_hat[i]:
           FN += 1

    return(TP, FP, TN, FN)
```

but it return me

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>   How can I fix that or maybe there are the better decision?

Answer (score 1):

The error message happens because Python tries to convert an array to a boolean and fails.

That's because you're comparing `y_actual` with `y_hat[i]`.

It should be `y_actual[i] != y_hat[i]` (2 times in the code)

(I realize that it's just a typo, but the message is cryptic enough for the problem to become interesting)

While we're at it, you could make a more efficient routine by merging all your counters in a sole loop and using enumerate to avoid at least one access by index:

```
def classification(y_actual, y_hat):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0

    for i,yh in enumerate(y_hat): 
        if y_actual[i] == yh == 1:
           TP += 1
        if y_actual[i] == 1 and y_actual[i] != yh:
           FP += 1
        if y_actual[i] == yh == 0:
           TN += 1
        if y_actual[i] == 0 and y_actual[i] != yh:
           FN += 1

    return(TP, FP, TN, FN)
```

you see that this way it can be even be simplified even more
, cutting a lot through tests and branches:

```
def classification(y_actual, y_hat):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0

    for i,yh in enumerate(y_hat): 
        if y_actual[i] == yh:
           if yh == 1:
               TP += 1
           elif yh == 0:
               TN += 1
        else: # y_actual[i] != yh
           if y_actual[i] == 1 and :
              FP += 1
           elif y_actual[i] == 0:
              FN += 1

    return(TP, FP, TN, FN)
```

Comment: but in the first and third cases that should be equal, but in the first case there are equal to `1`, but it the third there are equal to `0`

Comment: @Petr you are missing the point, Jean is simply pointing you to the obvious bug - that you forgot about `[i]` at the end of two lines. Fix it, and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I use `confusion_matrix` from `sklearn.metrics` and it return me need matrix.